# Entity Framework updating edmx creates duplicate properties

Tags: entity-framework

When I update my edmx from database ( I added primary keys on many-to-many relation table)
I get duplicated properties like 
InstantceType and InstanctType1, for each refresh from db I get a new property

any idea as to what is causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably that the EF model has become confused (corrupted) after the keys were added. A many-to-many table is a bit special, since it will not show up as an entity in an EF diagram if it only contains keys.

To fix this problem, the simplest solution would be to delete the model and then regenerate it.

Comment: That's bad because we have many derived classes and multiple class per table, we would need to recreate all the derived classes

Comment: I did have to remove some classes are re-add them, it then work. I did not have to rebuild all the model