# Properties are listed twice in variable, but not in class

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

So I have a simple class that represents data from the database.

```
public class EntitySyncContext
{
    public EntitySyncContext()
    {
        ExternalEntities = new List<ExternalContact>();
    }
    public HandledType HandledType { get; set; }
    public Contact Entity { get; set; }
    public IList<ExternalContact> ExternalEntities { get; set; }
    public bool HasConflict { get; set; }
}
```

But when I declare a variable from this class, when I put a watch on it while debugging I see that all of the properties that are listed above exist twice within the variable.

```
EntitySyncContext matchingContext = new EntitySyncContext();
```

[image: Printscreen of properties]

Does anyone know how and/or why this happens and/or how to fix it?

Comment: `Properties are listed twice` - can you provide screenshot to see what you mean?

Comment: Do you mean that each property has a backing field with a `Field` postfix?

Comment: Are you sure you're not seeing the backing field?

Comment: Are you using any extensions that could cause this?

Comment: @Sinatr Printscreen has been added

Comment: @Gravinco It looks like a bug with the VS debugger. Does it happen after restarting VS?

Comment: @Rob I just restarted VS and it still happens, I also checked with a colleague of mine and he has the same problem with that code on another pc

Comment: @Gravinco Can you post the entire file? I'll have a look locally. Also, where is the template TE defined? (Or is it a type? If so - can you also post the contents of TE?)

Comment: What types does your type inherit from?

Comment: @Rob TE represents data that comes from external systems so that we can work generically, at the moment it only represents the superclass and the interfaces implemented in ExternalContact. And what file did you want me to post, where the class EntitySyncContext is defined or where the variable is initialized?

Comment: @CodeCaster What type do you mean?

Comment: I mean your type `EntitySyncContext`. Is the code you show all code?

Comment: Just for fun, what happens if you change the variable names so they're not identical to the class names?

Comment: @Gravinco I tried it locally with some empty classes (`Contact` and `ExternalContact`). Couldn't reproduce it. What version of VS are you using? I also noticed, there is large space before 'Entity' in your screenshot, as well as the namespace for 'matchingContext'. Not sure if it's related, but it's baffled me.

Comment: May be you'be closed and opened the Watch window several times? What happens after restarting? Does it reappear right after it or after some time?

Comment: @mikeTheLiar I have commented out 2 of the properties to see what happened and for both properties, both entries in the variable were gone

Comment: What version of VS are you using?

Comment: @Rob I'm running VS 2013 and the large space is because I whited out part of the namespace because I can't give away too many details about the project because it's confidential.

Comment: @mikeTheLiar VS 2013

Comment: And these are watches? Not the immediate window?

Comment: @mikeTheLiar The printscreen you're looking at is a watch on the variable I first noticed the problemn in.

Comment: Try using reflection over an instance to print the members to the immediate window. If duplicates don't show up there then it's probably an add-in or extension malfunctioning.

Comment: Hi Gravinco, refer the following link...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7827780/entity-framework-updating-edmx-creates-duplicate-properties

Comment: @Gravinco without more of your "confidential" code we can't help you. I have repeatedly tried to reproduce your problem with the provided code to no avail

Comment: @Gravinco What happens if you toggle "Show raw structure of objects in variables windows" in Options -> Debugging -> General ?

Comment: You may want to try disabling any extensions you have installed, just to rule out that they're interfering with the watch window in some way.

Answer (score 3):

I only have VIsual Studio 2015 installed right now so behavior may be different but it got me thinking about a couple of things.

Look at this code here:

```
public interface IA
{
    string StringA { get; }
}

public interface IB
{
        string StringA { get; }
}

public class B
{
    public string StringA { get; }
}

public class A : B, IA, IB
{
    public string StringA
    {
        get
        {
            return "A";
        }
    }

    string IB.StringA
    {
        get
        {
            return "B";
        }
    }
}
```

Here is what watching an instance of class A looks like in Visual Studio 2015:

[image: The watch window of a very weird class]

So my thinking is that you have either explicitly implemented interfaces that have the same properties, or you could be hiding properties of a base class by declaring properties by the same name in a subclass, and Visual Studio 2013 either doesn't display the extra type detail that 2015 does, or you have it configured differently than I do.

Answer (score 0):

You can repair or reinstall IDE. It seems an IDE problem.

Answer (score -2):

I'd say it's a bug.

Declaring the public property with no private setter implies in the code behind the private setter is generated, most likely being picked up in the IDE